# Why does my c++ program work wrongly when I use that variable?

Tags: c++, variables

I have a function :

```
#include "motHasard.h"

    std::string motHasard(std::string mot)
    {
        srand(time(0));
        std::string motnew("");
        int position;
        while(mot.size()!=0)
        {
    
            position = rand() % mot.size();
    
            motnew+=mot[position];
            mot.erase(position,1);
        }
        return motnew;
    }
```

if I use a variable rather than `mot.size()` ( in the `while`, or for `position`) and run the program, it stops and bug when main() call the function `motHasard`.
But like that, it works perfectly.

Why can't I put the `.size()`in a variable and just use it ?

Like that :

```
#include "motHasard.h"

    std::string motHasard(std::string mot)
    {
        srand(time(0));
        std::string motnew("");
        int taille=mot.size();
        int position;
        while(taille!=0)
        {
    
            position = rand() % taille;
    
            motnew+=mot[position];
            mot.erase(position,1);
        }
        return motnew;
    }
```

This one doesn't work

Comment: __C__ `!=` __C++__ `!=` __C__, They are differnet languages and demand to be treaed as such. :) Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Choose one and stick to that please.

Comment: You are aware that `mot.size()` changes following the call to `mot.erase`?

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes sorry i thought that maybe the same problem can exist in C as they look alike.

Comment: @Bathsheba what do you mean ? The function take a word, take a random letter in it and stock it in "motnew", then erase that letter in the first word ( to keep letters only unused )

Comment: I think you need to show the code that doesn't work.

Comment: `x = mot.size()` does not mean "`x` is always the same as `mot.size()`", but  "`x` has the value that `mot.size()` has *right now*".

Comment: @molbdnilo So you mean that i need to re-initialize the variable in the begginning of the while ? Cause if it was the trouble, the program would just keep running, but not bugging ?

Comment: You just forget `taille--;` in the loop

Comment: @Damien Ah yes it would be logic if the program just keep running ?

Comment: Is there no duplicate for "my variable is not a math equation" kind of questions?

Comment: @Pikate This is equivalent to `taille = taille - 1;`. You have to put it just after the `erase`. Then, `taille`will stay equal to `mot.size()`. But why not keeping your first simpler working code?

Comment: @Yunnosch That's specific and i didn't find any topic which answers my question, sorry.

Comment: You can't re-initialize a variable, but you can re-*assign* it. Using a variable instead of the  condition you're really interested in makes the code less clear and (as you have noticed) error-prone. The loop that most directly expresses your intent is `while(!mot.empty()) ...`

Comment: @Damien I use the first working code.. but you know, i hate to do something and not knowing why it works, or why it is not working

Comment: @molbdnilo ok nice to you, thanks !

Comment: I think I will use this as duplicate. Maybe it provokes others into showing me a better one. Can I ask you not to close this?

Comment: @Yunnosch no problem!

Comment: Kind of you. But as you see, not your choice...

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting that the value of the variable needs to be re-calculated, this is your piece of code:

```
        int taille=mot.size();
        int position;
        while(taille!=0)
        {
    
            position = rand() % taille;
    
            motnew+=mot[position];
            mot.erase(position,1);
        }
```

So, you start with `taille` being the CURRENT size of `mot` (imagine that it is 12).
As long as you don't re-calculate it, the value will stay 12, even when `mot` changes, so you need following correction:

```
        int taille=mot.size();
        int position;
        while(taille!=0)
        {
    
            position = rand() % taille;
    
            motnew+=mot[position];
            mot.erase(position,1);
            taille=mot.size();           // <--- never forget to re-calculate the while-variable
        }
```

Comment: That is right, and thanks you for that. But if it was "the" trouble, the program would just don't stop (?)

Comment: @Pikate: no, just the opposite: the while-loop only stops when the condition is met, which will never happen as the condition does not get re-calculated.

Comment: So if "taille" never get re-calculated, it keep its value. So the while-loop condition will never be met, so the loop should keep running ? @Dominique

Comment: @Pikate: indeed.